# Why did the .NET designers not keep all exceptions in the System namespace?

Tags: c#, namespaces

Today I was working in C# and tried to catch a `FileNotFoundException`. But I wasn't able to do so until I added `using System.IO`.

Why was `FileNotFoundException` included in the `System.IO` namespace and not in the `System` namespace?

I understand that `FileNotFoundException` will be caused by an IO only, hence maybe the reason.  But on the other hand, shouldn't all `Exception`s be in the `System` namespace?

Comment: Exceptions in Java are kept in different namespaces too.

Comment: @zneak I think they are all under `java.lang.Exception`.

Comment: FileNotFoundException is derived from Exception but is in the System.IO dll & Namespace [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filenotfoundexception.aspx)

Comment: [`FileNotFoundException` is under `java.io`.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/FileNotFoundException.html)

Comment: @KazekageGaara java.lang.Exception is a class, not a namespace. Java exceptions inherit from java.lang.Exception but are kept in different namespaces (for example, FileNotFoundException is in the java.io namespace). In C#, the same principle applies - all exceptions inherit from System.Exception, and live in different namespaces - such as FileNotFoundException being in System.IO. Both languages are essentially the same in this respect.

Comment: @Chris I understand it now. It's pretty stupid on my part to ask such a thing before actually reading out things properly on my own first. Thanks though. :-)

Comment: By that reasoning, shouldn't all "objects" be under System, since "System.Object" is under the System namespace?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Code that belongs together should be kept together. This is one of the [key aspects of modular programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_programming#Key_aspects), which OOP belongs to.

The code in `System.IO` is the code likely to throw a `FileNotFoundException`, not any other code.

In the same way that `SqlException` is in the `System.Data.SqlClient` namespace.

It makes no sense to put all types of exceptions together, in particular for exception types that are very specific to certain usages (like database access).

Answer (score 2):

> I understand that `FileNotFoundException` will be caused by an IO only,
>   hence maybe the reason. But on the other hand, shouldn't all
>   Exceptions be kept under Exception?

Below is heirarchy showing where is `FileNotFoundException` located. So to answer your question it is a child (rather say Grand-Grand Child) of the `Exception class`

```
System.Object 
  System.Exception
    System.SystemException
      System.IO.IOException
        System.IO.FileNotFoundException
```

Answer (score 2):

Think about it like this:  You create your own `CustomClass` in its very own `CustomNamespace`.  Wouldn't it make sense that your `CustomException` be defined within `CustomNamespace` since that is where its context is understood?

Also, imagine if every single exception type is defined in one place.  A complete mess!

We use [namespaces](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Namespace) to give us **context** AND to **logically organise** our types.

Answer (score 2):

[`FileNotFoundException`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.IO.FileNotFoundException.aspx) is a class that is derived from [`Exception`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.exception.aspx) (or, more accurately, derived from a chain of classes that eventually derive from [`Exception`).](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.exception.aspx) You can't really put [`FileNotFoundException`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.IO.FileNotFoundException.aspx) "under" [`Exception`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.exception.aspx) unless maybe you're talking about making it an inner class. But that would require putting it in the same assembly as [`Exception`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.exception.aspx), which doesn't scale at all. When the team working on `System.SomeNewFeature.dll` wanted to create an exception, they couldn't put it into `mscorlib.dll` with [`Exception`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.exception.aspx) - it had to go in their code.

Beyond the necessity of doing that, it is possible for them to just shove it in whatever namespace they want. But it just makes sense from a grouping/organization standpoint. You only have (quick) access to the [`Exception`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.exception.aspx)s that are relevant to what you're working on. If they were all in `System` then it'd be crazy complicated.

Answer (score 1):

Generally you want to keep your exception in the scope they handle (keep your code grouped). If you think about it, putting `FileNotFoundException` makes sens to be in `System.IO` as that handles file system interaction.  Even if the exception is not in the `System.Exception` namespace it still inherits form System.Exception.  It's very unlikely that some other code will throw the `FileNotFoundException`. Just like it's unlikely that something interacting with the file system will throw a `System.Net.WebException`